# How to access win32com.client?

Tags: python, import, importerror, pywin32

I am trying do import win32com.client but I keep running into the ModuleNotFound Error.

When I try to install it, I get the following error message.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32